# Get UIFont for content size category

Tags: ios, uifont, uifontdescriptor

`UIFont` provides the [`+preferredFontForTextStyle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/preferredFontForTextStyle:) method to get a font instance with the proper size **based on the user's selected content size category** and the given [`UIFontTextStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Text_Styles).

What I would like to do is get a font for a given text style **and** content size. Something like `+fontForContentSizeCategory:andTextStyle:`.

Unfortunately I cannot find anything similar to that in the headers for [`UIFont`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/) or [`UIFontDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/).

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, both `+[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:]` and `+[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:]` rely on `-[UIApplication preferredContentSizeCategory]` internally. They use a private function `_CTFontDescriptorCreateWithTextStyle` to retrieve a CoreText font descriptor with specific text style and size category, and that's eventually based on a category → size mapping from the configuration file `CoreTextConfig.plist` stored somewhere, but I assume you wouldn't want to use private APIs.

While hesitantly implying a possibility to dynamically swizzle `-[UIApplication preferredContentSizeCategory]` to trick `+[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:]` into returning a font descriptor for the size class you want, I can't recommend any specific approach to this. You can retrieve a font descriptor like this:

```
let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: [ UIFontDescriptorTextStyleAttribute : UIFontTextStyleBody ])
```

but it won't contain a size attribute, so you would be left with trying to come up with a category → size mapping yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS 10.0 this is possible using `UITraitCollection`:

```
let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(preferredContentSizeCategory: contentSizeCategory)
let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle, compatibleWith: traitCollection)
```